# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^n+(-2)^n}{n-2^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Solve:
 $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^n+(-2)^n}{n-2^n}$$
So,it does seem that  $(-2)^n$ sequence is bounded( i think the bounds are -2 and 2) also, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n-2^n}$ =0 . I believe that the answer should be 0 . Could you help me out ?

Comment: You should take a closer look. What is $(-2)^3$, for instance?

Comment: Let $a_n=\frac{2^n+(-2)^n}{n-2^n}$. Take a look at the subsequences $a_n=a_{2k}$ and $a_n=a_{2k+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For odd $n$ the numerator is $0$. For even $n$ we get $\frac {2 (2^{n})} {n-2^{n}}=\frac 2 {n/2^{n}-1}$ which tends to $-2$. So the given limit does not exist.

Note that $2^{n} =(1+1)^{n}>\binom {n} {2} =\frac {n(n-1)} 2$ so $\frac {2^{n}} n \to \infty$. This implies $\frac n {2^{n}} \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=\dfrac{2^2+(-2^n)}{n-2^n}$;

Numerator : $2^n(1+(-1)^n)$;

Denominator $2^n(n/(2^n)-1)$;

1) $n =2k+1$: $a_{2k+1}=0$;

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_{2k+1}=0$;

2) $n=2k$: $a_{2k}=\dfrac{2}{n/2^n-1}$;

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_{2k}=-2.$

Hence?